# DateTime format in YAML configuration

Tags: php, datetime, yaml, symfony

Configuring JMSSerializerBundle, I only find examples on date formatting for Annotations, but not on how set it in YAML, so:

Which is the equivalent in YAML for this

```
@Type("DateTime<'Y-m-d'>")
```

For now, this is working,

```
dob:
  expose: true
  type: DateTime
```

but the output is the one set in the main config, so

```
handlers:
        datetime:
            default_format: "c" # ISO8601
            default_timezone: "UTC"
```

outputs

```
"1982-06-06T00:00:00+02:00"
```

I want it to be

```
"1982-06-06"
```

as is a birth date and I don't care for the time

Comment: `default_format: "Y-m-d"`

Comment: @malcolm do you mean in the main config? I want to do this per field and not globally, as I will also have datetimes fully represented. Using default_format in the serialization config throws "Unable to parse at line 24 (near \"  default_format: \"Y-m-d\"\") I though there was a Date option instead DateTime but it doesn't seems to work

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @dVaffection actually not. I finally changed to annotation for serialization. I just use @JMS\Type("DateTime<'Y-m-d'>")

Answer (score 0):

This snippet works for me

```
AcmeBundle\Document\User:
  properties:
    id:
      type: string
      groups: [list, detailed]
    #...
    birthday:
      type: DateTime<'Y-m-d'>
      groups: [detailed]
    #...
    createdAt:
      type: DateTime<'Y-m-d H:i:s'>
      groups: [detailed]
```

You may of course specify one default format in the global configuration, and then customise it on a property level when needed (birthday in your case).